# EF Core/Azure SQL DB: How to run migrations without deleting current data in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, .net-5, ef-core-3.1

I have deployed a SQL database on Azure SQL database and published an API in .NET 5.0, however, EF Core/Database is an area I'm lacking a little knowledge in.

Right now I have a lot of data in the database I had to input manually and I don't want to have to input everything again because I didn't ask the "stupid question".

**What I'm trying to do:**

Be able to run migrations anytime whether I'm modifying a table or creating a new one
without deleting data in production

**Problem:**

the Seed Data is in the DbContext ( in OnModelCreating )
and have been added to the first migration.
Before I apply the new migration I've generated the Migration Script twice,
once with the seed data uncommented and once commented.

THE NEW TABLE I'M TRYING TO ADD IS `Sectors` and there is no Seed Data for it.

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<...>().HasData(new Device
        {
            // ...
        });
    //
    // All the seed data is added this way
    //
}
```

**Uncommented:**

Up: Adds new tables and doesn't do anything about seed data ( just some hours from StoreHours table, confusing )

Down: Drops new tables

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace App.Persistence.Migrations
{
public partial class SeedDataUncommented: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
            name: "SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            type: "uniqueidentifier",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Sectors",
            columns: table => new
            {
                SectorId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                City = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                CreatedDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Sectors", x => x.SectorId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("25c68145-c5a3-438d-8cd4-acaec481384d"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 17, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("3ad512e7-1aca-4339-9341-9b4028bb0536"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 17, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("3f99ba19-f6e5-4e5d-afcf-d10f0ebc6009"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 22, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2022, 1, 22, 11, 30, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        //
        // A bunch of other migrationBuilder.UpdateData( table: "StoreHours") I think because the Seed Data generates a new DateTime object everytime
        //

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Places_SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            column: "SectorId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Places_Sectors_SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            column: "SectorId",
            principalTable: "Sectors",
            principalColumn: "SectorId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Places_Sectors_SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Sectors");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Places_SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("25c68145-c5a3-438d-8cd4-acaec481384d"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("3ad512e7-1aca-4339-9341-9b4028bb0536"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "StoreHours",
            keyColumn: "StoreHourId",
            keyValue: new Guid("3f99ba19-f6e5-4e5d-afcf-d10f0ebc6009"),
            columns: new[] { "CloseHour", "OpenHour" },
            values: new object[] { new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 22, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), new DateTime(2021, 11, 10, 11, 30, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified) });

        //
        // A bunch of other migrationBuilder.UpdateData( table: "StoreHours") I think because the Seed Data generates a new DateTime object everytime
        //
    }
}
```

}

**Commented:**

Up: Deletes all the seed data

Down: Runs migrationBuilder.InsertData() for every table that was from the seed data.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

namespace App.Persistence.Migrations
{
public partial class SeedDataCommented : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "Addresses",
            keyColumn: "AddressId",
            keyValue: new Guid("16121702-bdf9-4444-a8b6-b08b33bb8eec"));

        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "Addresses",
            keyColumn: "AddressId",
            keyValue: new Guid("2de4a3c8-a391-4f00-8d10-c06b5bdb7629"));

        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "Categories",
            keyColumn: "CategoryId",
            keyValue: new Guid("066f36ea-bbbb-4243-e55d-08d91f53840e"));

        migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
            table: "Categories",
            keyColumn: "CategoryId",
            keyValue: new Guid("e53265e0-a52b-46f0-abb2-08d91f5485bc"));

        //
        // migrationBuilder.DeleteData() for every previously added Seed Data
        //

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
            name: "SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            type: "uniqueidentifier",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Sectors",
            columns: table => new
            {
                SectorId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                City = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                CreatedDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Sectors", x => x.SectorId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Places_SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            column: "SectorId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Places_Sectors_SectorId",
            table: "Places",
            column: "SectorId",
            principalTable: "Sectors",
            principalColumn: "SectorId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Places_Sectors_SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Sectors");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Places_SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "SectorId",
            table: "Places");

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "Categories",
            columns: new[] { "CategoryId", "CreatedBy", "CreatedDateTime", "ImageUrl", "Name" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
                // Seed Data
            });

        //
        // a bunch of other migrationBuilder.InsertData() for all the Seed Data
        //
    }
}
```

}

In both cases when I run `Add-Migration` it throws a warning message saying "may result in the loss of data"

How should I do it?

Comment: YES.  A migration can definitely delete data.  Instead of automatically applying them you may want to generate a migration script instead.  You can then review the script and create a backup of your DB before running it in your server's sql management tool... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: you can rollback migrations... it will keep a history of them, but not sure it would restore data that had been lost. (?)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, what would be in the script that would indicate potential loss of data ?

Comment: If you see a drop or alter of a table or field you may lose data...  This is only SQL that affects the structure of the database.... it does nothing to the data unless the change to the structure causes a drop.  (It doesn't affect the actual data... your local server database will still have different data than production... it does nothing to sync the data itself, just the changes to the structure of the database.)  The script shows you what changes would be made.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop_table.asp

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins but then why does data gets synced let’s say during the first migration when there is seed data added to the migration script ? What if there still is, can it corrupt/break some things ?

Comment: seeding should be separate from migrations... not sure why that would be in there.  Usually you'd put those calls in Program.cs.  (and the seeds should check for certain conditions before executing... if it's an initial seed, it would check if there are any records first...)  I usually comment those out after they are run for the first time in each environment...

Comment: I see, to understand my env, the Seed Data is in the DbContext ( in `OnModelCreating` ) and have been added to the first migration. Before I apply the new migration I've generated the Migration Script twice, once with the seed data uncommented and once commented, the uncommented pretty much doesn't take the seed data into account in the Up method so it just adds the new table but with the seed data commented, it deletes all the seed data in the Up method and in the Down method it runs `migrationBuilder.InsertData()` for every table that were from the seed data. Do you know what's happening ?

Comment: I wouldn't don't do that.  Just have your seeds run when the program starts up.  Still, since this isn't a change to the model, it shouldn't be included in the migration script.  Adding a table isn't a part of a "seed".... that's a change to the model and so a part of your migration (which EF is synching with your database)  That's the structure of your DB (along with some other attributes which the DB doesn't really track...things like display name, required, etc...)  So create your seeds as separate .cs class files and run them at run-time.

Comment: Looking at the current docs, it looks like MS is recommended doing this differently now.  I'm not too sure why, really... they talk about concurrency, but if the proper checks are there it will only run once.  I can't say I know more than MS about this, so maybe you are already doing it properly... I used the method (older?) described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#seed-the-database-2

Comment: I see what you're talking about, I did the same thing for my user seed in the program.cs so I'll try to move it there and see what, it does. Thank you so much for your help I'll let you know as soon as I've tried if it worked or not

Comment: I think the difference would be if you are doing database-first migrations, or model-first migrations.  I do model-first.  It sounds like you are doing db-first.   I don't set relationships using the builder, so I can't say whether separating the seed/migration is best for you.

Comment: I have to say that model-first seems much simpler... you don't have to create ups or downs, or anything really... it will track changes to your model and generate the migration and SQL scripts for you.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more easy to understand, I tried to make it more narrow

Comment: not sure why you are deleting data in your migration.  Why would you do that?  If these are initial seeds, just check if the table has any records first.  Remember your local/develop DB is separate from the server/production DB.  You shouldn't be trying to sync these DBs.

Comment: Exactly, am I syncing them the way I'm doing it right now ? If so, how do I prevent syncing them when updating the DB ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely. The EF core has drawback in code first approach like whenever you change anything to the respestive table it will effected data too.

Suppose as an example.

I have table `Test`

```
TestId
TestName
TestAdd
Testxyz
```

I have data in table like below:

```
TestId TestName TestAdd Testxyz
1       a         b       c
2       b         c       d  
3       d         e       f
4       e         f       g
```

for above table if I remove the column from entity table so that will surely remove data also, but EF core will be give you a warning  in Package manager console like **`There might be some changes in file will affected to database kindly review the migration file`**.

Comment: I see, and does it highlights what will get deleted in the migration script ? Like I'm sure it tells the actual column that gets deleted and so the records of that column will get deleted too ( which I expect ) but can it "accidentally" delete every record of the entity in the DB ? What I mean is, if there are 30 users lets say, if I add a new migration that doesn't even touch the Users table, can the next migration somehow delete every users for some reason ? Such as known EF Core bug or mistype or potential error ?

Comment: My problem is that my local DB and my production DB don't have the same records in them so I feel like if I run a migration, it will somehow mistake the data from the local DB, the seed data and the new one and maybe delete all the data in the production DB

Comment: Table records won't affected to the table. If you made any changes in column data type or remove column from entity then and then the data of the table of respective column will be deleted.

Comment: For your question `What I mean is, if there are 30 users lets say, if I add a new migration that doesn't even touch the Users table, can the next migration somehow delete every users for some reason ?` the next migration won't delete your user table data if you do not perform any changes in user table entity. If you made changes then data of the respective column will be deleted else no migration will affected.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer, one last precision, the fact that there are Seed Data in the DbContext ( in the `OnModelCreating` method ) that have been added to the first migration, do I need to comment/delete them or can I just leave it there and run the migration anyway ? Also, can the data in the local DB be confused and pushed to the production DB by accident ?

Comment: Does your first migration already updated to production database?

Comment: I had the local database with some seed data and pushed it to the production database using the Microsoft Data Migration Assistant, now since I've made my production DB get updated using the Publish tool in Visual Studio I haven't ran any other migration

Comment: Have you perform migration in production before this or you are going to do it first time.

Comment: This is going to be the first time

Comment: Okay then if you want to keep seed data to production then keep it with or you can comment it is upto you.

Comment: Cool so commenting it will not change anything to the data that's in the production DB ? After all if it could create a problem will EF Core let me know ?

Comment: Review this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Alright so before I apply the migration I've generated the Migration Script twice, once with the seed data uncommented and once commented, the uncommented pretty much doesn't take the seed data into account in the `Up` method so it just adds the new table but with the seed data commented, it deletes all the seed data in the `Up` method and in the `Down` method it runs `migrationBuilder.InsertData()` for every table that were from the seed data. Do you know what's happening ?

Comment: This is what it says about EF Core Seed Data : `Migrations only considers model changes when determining what operation should be performed to get the seed data into the desired state. Thus any changes to the data performed outside of migrations might be lost or cause an error.` Link : [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more easy to understand, I tried to make it more narrow